# iOS Get Connection

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

This is my first time on this site and I am very new to coding so I was wondering if somebody could help me out.

I want to set a get request from my iphone app to my website and get the information echoed back from the website to my phone.

I have gotten this far but do not know where to go from here. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
- (void)myData:(id)sender
{
  NSString *DataToBeSent;
  sender = [sender stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%20"];
  [receivedData release];
  receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  DataToBeSent = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://194.128.xx.xxx/doCalc/getInfo.php?Data=%@",sender];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataToBeSent] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
  [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
  NSError *requestError;
  NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;  
  NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
  [dataToBeSent release];
}
```

OLD WAY

```
- (void)myData:(id)sender
{
  NSString *dataToBeSent;
  sender = [sender stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%20"];
  [receivedData release];
  receivedData= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  dataToBeSent= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://194.128.xx.xxx/doCalc/getInfo.php?Data=%@",sender];
  NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataToBeSent]];
  Theconn= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
  NSLog (@"test1 %@", theRequest);
  NSLog (@"test2 %@", Theconn);
  [dataToBeSent release];
}
```

Then the following methods are called and I get my data BUT if I sent another request after my first one but different data on the same connection, it would always give me the same result which shouldn't happen

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  /* appends the new data to the received data */
  [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
  NSString *stringData= [[NSString alloc] 
  initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
  NSLog(@"Got data? %@", stringData);
  [self displayAlertCode:stringData];    
  [stringData release];
  // Do unbelievably cool stuff here //
}
```

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data loaded properly you can convert the data into a string and do whatever you want with it.

```
NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

//Make sure to set the correct encoding
NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If your server returns JSON there are 3rd party libraries that can parse the string into collections like NSArray and NSDictionary. If your server returns XML then NSXMLParser could be something you can use.

**EDIT**

I've changed your code to manage the memory a little differently.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData * receivedData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURLConnection * Theconn;
```

.m

```
@synthesize receivedData;
@synthesize Theconn;

//A bunch of cool stuff


- (void)myData:(id)sender
{
    //If you already have a connection running stop the existing one
    if(self.Theconn != nil){
        [self.Theconn cancel];
    }

    sender = [sender stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%20"];

    //This will release your old receivedData and give you a new one
    self.receivedData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];


    NSString *dataToBeSent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://194.128.xx.xxx/doCalc/getInfo.php?    Data=%@",sender];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataToBeSent]];

    //This will release your old NSURLConnection and give you a new one
    self.Theconn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    NSLog (@"test1 %@", theRequest);
    NSLog (@"test2 %@", Theconn);

 }

 //...
 //Your delegate methods
 //...

 - (void) dealloc{
    [receivedData release];
    [Theconn release];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Comment: Joel, When I NSLog response1, it says its null. The data sent to the website from the iphone and then generated by the website is a simple string. Literally one word, someones name. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you do this NSLog(@"%@",requestError)

Comment: I believe you are getting that error because you are setting your timeOutInterval to 10 and its taking longer than 10 seconds for the response. If it's taking longer than 10 seconds that probably means it cannot find your server at all. Your IP Address looks like a router assigned it. Make sure that your device/simulator are both connected to the internet through the same router for them to be able to see the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help Joel... you seem to have a good grasp on these things so if you dont mind I would like to ask you one last question? I had it working before in a different way (will edit my question and post it there) but I feel like this was not the correct way to going about with the "GET" method? Can you please take a look, the code is very short. Thank you so much

Comment: So your edited code should solve my problem with the "GET" returning the same data every time after the first time initiated? Thanks one last time

Comment: Didnt fix the problem but I appreciate your help. If you have any other suggestions, let me know, If not, thanks again

Comment: Sorry Joel for yet another question but I think the problem has to do with the iphone caching the data coming in? just wondering is this a possibility and if there is an easy fix? thanks once again